# Model.OrderBy failing in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I've got an MVC 3 app that uses a couple of partial views but it is failing on this line

```
 title = "by " + Model.OrderBy.Field;
```

As far as I can tell I've got the right method in the model

```
        public OrderByInfo OrderBy
    {
        get { return _orderBy; }
    }
```

but it tells me OrderBy is a method, which is not valid in the given context.

Any ideas?

Comment: can't you do that code when you setup the ViewModel in the Controller? Why make life difficult for the Views?

Comment: Just trying to make some existing code work right now. It should but I'm not sure why it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being something to do with the project being opened up in VS2010. I'm running it with VS2008 and it's fine. I'll have to go through the upgrade process at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Is your model an `IEnumerable`. My guess is there might be some conflict with the the `OrderBy()` LINQ extension method. Is your `OrderBy` property defined on a class that is a collection of models or on a particular model?

Comment: I think it's just one model. I changed the name and it still couldn't reach the method so does that mean it can't see it from the view?